# Spring : previous Line in jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have this request :

```
private List<IWsResponse> getBPartnerDetails(String valueNetwork, String reportLevel2) {
        JdbcTemplate tm = new JdbcTemplate(ds.getDataSource());
        StringBuffer sql =  new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM XRV_BPARTNERDETAILS where rownum < 10 order by BPartner_ID");
        response = tm.query(sql.toString(),  new BPartnerMapper());
        return response;
    }
```

in the `BPartnerMapper`, i want to do the following :

get the previous elements in the ResultSet to compare it with actual line

```
@Override
    public IWsResponse mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        rs.previous();
        int prev_Bpartner_ID = rs.getInt("BPARTNER_ID");
        int prev_Location_ID = rs.getInt("BPARTNER_LOCATION_ID");
        int prev_User_ID = rs.getInt("User_ID");
        rs.next();
        int Bpartner_ID = rs.getInt("BPARTNER_ID");
        int Location_ID = rs.getInt("BPARTNER_LOCATION_ID");
        int User_ID = rs.getInt("User_ID");
        // My code
    }
```

I get the error in `rs.previous()` :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : previous
```

how can i fix that to get the `previous` elements of `resultSet`

Comment: Post the code where you are creating the `Statement`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `next()` or `previous()` in the first place in a `RowMapper`. You should use a `ResultSetExtractor` and simply iterate over the results (keep the last one and compare with the next one). Instead of going back and forward. You should also not create a `JdbcTemplate` each time you need one, performance wise not very smart to do as it is a heavy object to construct.

Comment: What is your use case, why do you need to do this comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `prev()` or `next()` on the ResultSet as it pre-initialized for the current row.

From the Spring Documentation of `mapRow()`:

> Implementations must implement this method to map each row of data in the ResultSet. This method should not call next() on the ResultSet; it is only supposed to map values of the current row.

What you should be doing instead is:

1. Get an `ArrayList` out of your `query()`.
2. Iterate this list and do the needed comparisons.